# SSIS Programmatic generation of an ODBC Connection

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create an ODBC destination source in an SSIS package using methods like the ones described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345167.aspx I can't seem to initialize the ODBC connection correctly.  Here is the code I'm using to create the ODBC Connection

```
    // Specify the connection manager.
    component1.RuntimeConnectionCollection.NewAt(0);
    if (component1.RuntimeConnectionCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        component1.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager =
          DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(myPackage.Connections["ODBC Connection"]);
        component1.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManagerID =
          myPackage.Connections["ODBC Vertica Connection"].ID;
        component1.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].Name = myPackage.Connections["ODBC Connection"].Name;
    }
```

When I attempt to connect to a server using this code I get a COM exception thrown.  Does anyone have an example of a working ODBC connection created using SSIS generation

I Create an instance from component1 using the code

```
CManagedComponentWrapper instance = component1.Instantiate();
```

When I attempt to initialize the metadata for the object using the connection the COM exception is thrown. The line throwing the exception reads

```
instance.AcquireConnections(null);
```

The COM Exception itself is

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Which translates to System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException error code -2147467259

Here is the code in its entirety.  I attempt to add a an ODBC Destination to an existing Data Flow component

```
    private IDTSComponentMetaData100 addODBCDest(MainPipe dataFlow_pipe, String tableName)
    {
        // ADO Net Data Source
        IDTSComponentMetaData100 component1 = dataFlow_pipe.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
        component1.Name = tableName + " ODBC Destination";
        Application app = new Application();

        component1.ComponentClassID = "{074B8736-CD73-40A5-822E-888215AF57DA}";
        // Get the design time instance of the component.
        CManagedComponentWrapper instance = component1.Instantiate();

        // Initialize the component
        try
        {
            instance.ProvideComponentProperties();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        // Specify the connection manager.
        component1.RuntimeConnectionCollection.NewAt(0);
        if (component1.RuntimeConnectionCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            component1.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager =
              DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(myPackage.Connections["ODBC Connection"]);
            component1.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManagerID =
              myPackage.Connections["ODBC Vertica Connection"].ID;
            component1.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].Name = myPackage.Connections["ODBC Connection"].Name;
        }

        // Set the custom properties.
        instance.SetComponentProperty("InsertMethod", 1);
        instance.SetComponentProperty("BatchSize", 10000);

        // Reinitialize the metadata.
        instance.AcquireConnections(null);  // crashes with COM exception -2147467259
        instance.ReinitializeMetaData();
        instance.ReleaseConnections();
        return component1;
    }
```

Comment: What COM exception and what line is throwing it?

Comment: I Create an instance from component1 using the code CManagedComponentWrapper instance = component1.Instantiate(); When I attempt to initialize the metadata for the object using the connection the COM exception is thrown.  The line throwing the exception reads instance.AcquireConnections(null); The COM Exception itself is {"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."} Which translates to System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException error code -2147467259

Comment: Are you trying to create the connection manager **while the package is executing**? (There's a very straightforward example of creating a new connection programatically in the [Adding Connections Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136093.aspx) article in MSDN, but it doesn't look like that's what you're trying to do.)

Comment: Could you post the code in its entirety? Edit the existing question as I think we're missing something in the doling out of information.

Comment: I'm trying to add a connection to a new package not during package execution.  The connection is created using the code example from the link at MSDN.  However, when I attempt to use the connection to refresh the metadata for a dataflow component, the connection fails.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code, it makes it easier to see the whole picture. If you do not do the last 3 lines of `instance` code and generate the package, code-wise it *should*? complete and then you could serialize the XML out, yes? I had a devil of a time generating SSIS package from an ODBC source and what I found helpful was to write the package out, open in BIDS and verify that what I was changing was doing what I *thought* it should.

Comment: It may not matter, but I always created my Connection Managers prior to mucking with the Data Flow components.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, was a solution found?